# Rendering with studio light setup in World

Tags: rendering, world

I have built a perfect setup on the Viewport with **only** studiolight, in my case sunset.exr, rotation 69 degrees and strength 0.4. When I switch the Viewport to Render mode (I work with 2.90 and Cycles) I see a perfect image. I have configured the World with the same sunset.exr image in order to get the same result on the rendered image, but I don’t know how to tweak the 69 degrees and therefore when I click F12 the resulting rendered image is different from the one on the Viewport. What should I do in order to get a rendered image result that is identical to the one on the viewport? BTW, clicking on View>Viewport Render Image does not work. Thank you for your kind advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Mapping node for that.

1. Add a Texture Coordinate node and a Mapping node before your HDRI
2. Rotate around Z axis
3. Done

[image]

Comment: Jachym Michal, thank you so much for your detailed reply which fully solves my problem. Thank you for that.